# Momentum operator in spherical coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, coordinate-systems

In the position representation the momentum operator takes the form of the gradient, $-i\hbar \nabla$.

It is understood that  its components denote $p_{x}, p_{y}, p_{z}$ respectively; but, when transforming the gradient to spherical coordinates, what do the individual radial, polar and azimuthal components represent?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9349/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/224027/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Useful [background](https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0021013).

Comment: Can you sharpen your question? Which aspect of the conversion are you  seeking to enlighten? Are you aware of the conversion formulas?

Comment: So for example looking at the gradient in spherical coordinates, the radial component of the vector is not thought of as the expected classical radial momentum. Nevertheless this radial component appears in the momentum operator in spherical coordinates. So my question is what does it represent?

Comment: Something bothering you about the linked answers? Are you fully comfortable with the appendix of the linked paper?