# Relativistic correction to the enrgy spectrum of the Hydrogen atom for $l=0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, mathematical-physics, hydrogen

I am studying the fine structure of the hydrogen atom. The non relativistic Hamiltonian of the Hydrogen atom is given by
$$\hat{H}_{\mathrm{non-rel}}=\frac{\hat{\textbf{P}}^{2}}{2m_{e}}-\frac{e^{2}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}|\hat{\textbf{R}}|}$$
We can replace the non relativistic kinetic energy term with a first order expansion of the relativistic kinetic energy, doing so obtains the folowing the Hamiltonian
\begin{align*}
    \hat{H}&=\frac{\hat{\textbf{P}}^{2}}{2m_{e}}-\frac{e^{2}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}|\hat{\textbf{R}}|}-\frac{(\hat{\textbf{P}}^{2})^{2}}{8m_{e}^{3}c^{2}}\\&=\hat{H}_{\mathrm{non-rel}}+\hat{V}
\end{align*}
For
$$\hat{V}=-\frac{(\hat{\textbf{P}}^{2})^{2}}{8m_{e}^{3}c^{2}}$$
Since the perturbation, $\hat{V}$, is spherically symmetric, it is possible to apply non degenerate perturbation theory to calculate the perturbed energy. In order to evaluate this perturbation I expressed the perturbation as follows
\begin{equation}
\hat{V}=-\frac{1}{2m_{e}c^{2}}\left(\hat{H}_{\mathrm{non-rel}}+\frac{e^{2}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}|\hat{\textbf{R}}|}\right)^{2}
\end{equation}
As seen in Sakurai *Modern quantum mechanics*. The result is that we have a first order perturbation of
$$\Delta_{nl}^{(1)}=\frac{(E_{n}^{(0)})^{2}}{2m_{e}c^{2}}\left(3-\frac{4n}{l+\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$
where
$$E_{n}^{(0)}=-\frac{m_{e}}{2\hbar^{2}}\left(\frac{e^{2}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\right)^{2}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$$
is the unperturbed energy. I have now read an alternative source [[1](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node107.html)], which suggests this derivation is not correct for $l=0$, since the operator $(\hat{\textbf{P}}^{2})^{2}$ is not Hermitian for $l=0$, however **coincidentally** this derivation provides the correct result for $l=0$.  Therefore, my questions are:

1. Why would $(\hat{\textbf{P}}^{2})^{2}$ by non Hermitian for $l=0$?

2.Why does this mean that my expression $\hat{V}=-\frac{1}{2m_{e}c^{2}}\left(\hat{H}_{\mathrm{non-rel}}+\frac{e^{2}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}|\hat{\textbf{R}}|}\right)^{2}
$ is invalid?

Comment: https://physicaeducator.files.wordpress.com/2018/01/solutions-of-quantum-mechanics-by-griffith.pdf Page 165 (answer to Q6.15) has a good answer for this if anyone in the future has the same question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The problem is that some of the boundary terms at $r=0$ when trying to show self-adjointness
   $$ \langle \psi_{n00}, p^4 \psi_{m00}\rangle = \langle p^4\psi_{n00},\psi_{m00}\rangle$$
   do not disappear for the $\ell = 0$ hydrogen states. See [this answer by ZeroTheHero](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/343564/50583) for a similar issue with the mere $p_r$, the problem for $p_r^4$ is similar but more severe since it contains higher powers of $\frac{1}{r}$.
2. Perturbation theory assumes the Hamiltonian is Hermitian. The results may be correct, but strictly speaking you cannot apply perturbation theory to something that's not Hermitian.

Comment: In the 2nd edition of Griffiths, he says that $\hat{p}^4$ is not Hermitian for the $l=0$ states. However, in the 3rd edition, he *corrects* this and says that in fact he was wrong; it *is* Hermitian, and to show this, we are meant to use the identity$$\nabla^4(e^{-kr}) = \left(-\frac{4k^3}{r}+k^4\right)e^{-kr}+8\pi k\delta^{(3)}(\vec{r})$$. He seems to imply that it's the extra delta-function that fixes the issue, but I'm not sure. What do you think?

Comment: @march The problem is probably more subtle and related to domain issues: Since $p$ is unbounded it can only be densely defined and you need to start with the correct domain of definition for $p$ to make it self-adjoint. Then you have to apply functional calculus carefully to figure out what the domain of $p^4$ is, and I think it indeed turns out that the $\ell = 0$ states will not lie inside its domain (but *would* be self-adjoint). This does not mean that you can't find some way to apply $p^4$ to states outside this domain, only that you *mustn't do that* if you want to keep it self-adjoint.

Comment: In physics treatments that don't care about these details of functional analysis such issues show up variously as non-real eigenvalues, unexpected boundary terms or other apparent paradoxes (e.g. [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/233311/50583)). Note that Griffiths' cure is worse than the problem: If $p^4$ produces a $\delta$-function - which is *not* an element of the Hilbert space $L^2$! - then $p^4$ isn't even an operator from the Hilbert space to itself anymore, let alone self-adjoint.