# Expected momentum of ground state hydrogen $<p>$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, coordinate-systems, hydrogen

I am trying to calculate the expected momentum of an electron in the ground state of hydrogen atom. This is the wave function.

[image]

So far I have done this:$$\iiint_V \Psi^* (-i\hbar) \frac {d\Psi} {dr} r^2 sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi$$
But the answer I am getting is $$\frac {i\hbar}{a_b}$$ which looks wrong because it is imaginary. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The expectation value of the momentum $\langle \vec{p}\rangle$ is zero. So you don't have to bother about the $i$. Your calculus have to consider that $\nabla\psi$ is a vector when calculating $\langle \vec{p}\rangle=\int_V \psi^*(-i\hbar\nabla\psi)d^3x$

Comment: part of the problem might be tied to the use of spherical coordinates.  In particular, for the construction of the radial momentum operator, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9349/

Comment: Is the atom at rest?

Answer (score 2):

You simply miscalculated the action of $\vec p$ on spherically symmetric functions *f(r)*.

In actuality, your answer should transform vectorially,
$$
\vec p f(r)= -i\hbar \nabla f(r)= -i\hbar~  \hat x ~\partial_r f(r), 
$$
so, then, as @KevinDeNotariis suggests, 
$$
\langle \vec p \rangle= -i\hbar \int d^3x ~\psi^* \partial_r \psi(r) ~\frac{\vec x}{r} ,
$$ 
trivially vanishing upon integrating over all directions.