# Is the radial component of $p^2$ a hermitian operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, momentum

The kinetic energy of a system $p^2/2m$ in real space representation takes the form $-\hbar^2\nabla^2/2m$. I want to express this in cylindrical coordinates via the representation of the laplace operator [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates). This is
$$\nabla^2 = \frac{1}{r}\partial_r(r\partial_r)+\frac{1}{r^2}\partial^2_\varphi + \partial^2_z.$$ Expanding the radial part yields $\frac{1}{r}\partial_r+\partial^2_r$. While I know that the second derivative is a hermitian operator, this is not true for the first derivative. The factor if $i$ that comes with $$p = -i\hbar\nabla$$ takes care that the operator $p$ is really hermitian, however here it is missing. How can I see that the radial component is still hermitian in this representation?

Bonus: Eventually I want to implement this numerically using finite differences method. The stencil for $\partial^2_r$ is $[1,-2,1]$ which results in a hermitian matrix. For $\partial_r$ however, the stencil is $[-1/2,0,1/2]$ which takes a minus sign if I do hermitian conjugate.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9349/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The Laplacian is hermitian and so is the third term of the RHS of your equation. The second term in the RHS is also hermitian, since $1/r$ and $\partial_\phi$ commute. Hence the remaining term, the radial part, is hermitian.

Comment: The relevant Hilbert space is $L^2((0,+\infty), r^2 dr)$... that $r^2$ makes $(1/r)\partial_r(r \partial_r)$ Hermitian.