# How do we determine the conjugate of radial component of linear momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How do we describe the radial part of linear momentum?
[Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/9353) I found the following description:

> Classically
>
> $$p_r=\hat{D}_r = \frac{\hat{r}}{r} \cdot\hat{p} = \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$$
>
> However $\hat{D}_r$ is not hermitian. Consider the adjoint
>
> $$\hat{D}_r^\dagger= \hat{p}\cdot\frac{\hat{r}}{r} =\frac{\hbar}{i} \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{2}{r} \right )$$
>
> Now we know from linear algebra how to construct a hermitian operator from an operator and its adjoint:
>
> $$\hat{p}_r = \frac{\hat{D}_r^\dagger+\hat{D}_r}{2}=\frac{\hbar}{i} \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r} \right )$$

Can anyone clarify how conjugate is obtained?

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that there is no way to make the radial momentum operator self-adjoint. As to how to construct the formal conjugate and  and (if it exists) the  true conjuage see  our book (a draft is avaiable online [here](https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf)) chapter 4.