How to use quantum mechanics to get Bohr velocity $ v_n=\frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\boldsymbol{\hbar}}\frac1n $?
In atomic physics, we use Bohr Model to get the velocity electronic in Hydrogen-like atoms $ v_n=\frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\boldsymbol{\hbar}}\frac1n $, but how to use quantum mechanics, use Schrodinger equation to get it?
I try to calculate $ \langle \boldsymbol{p} \rangle $ in the ground state $ \psi_{100} = \sqrt{\frac{Z^3}{\pi a^3}}\exp[-\frac{Z}{a}r] $
\begin{align}
 \langle \boldsymbol{p} \rangle  = -i\hbar \frac{Z^{3}}{\pi a^{3}} \cdot 4\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} r^{2} \exp\left[-\frac{Z}{a}r\right] \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \exp\left[-\frac{Z}{a}r\right] \right)  \ {\rm d}r \  \boldsymbol{\mathrm{e}}_{r} 
  = \frac{8Z}{a}i\hbar \boldsymbol{\mathrm{e}}_{r} 
\end{align}
I know it must be a wrong answer. So, can we use the method in quantum to get the velocity $  v_n=\frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\boldsymbol{\hbar}}\frac1n $? Thanks by LiZ.

"I know it must be a wrong answer." Right, because $\langle \vec p \rangle$ must be zero in a stationary state like $\psi_{100}$ (or any real valued state).

You're not really calculating the radial part of the momentum, see e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/9353/226902

Upon some thought, it can be clarified that Bohr's velocity is really a root-mean-square velocity, i.e. $$v_n=\sqrt{\left<\frac{\vec p{}^{,2}}{m^2}\right>}$$ which then connects to both the virial theorem and the Hamiltonian, and thus the answer then follows directly from @hft 's answer below.

seems more like a principles question, not homework, but yes: $E=2T+V=-T\rightarrow \frac 1 2 mc^2 (Z/n)^2\alpha^2 = \frac 1 2 m v^2$ is the principle.


I try to calculate $ \langle \boldsymbol{p} \rangle $ in the ground state $ \psi_{100} = \sqrt{\frac{Z^3}{\pi a^3}}\exp[-\frac{Z}{a}r] $
\begin{align}
 \langle \boldsymbol{p} \rangle  = -i\hbar \frac{Z^{3}}{\pi a^{3}} \cdot 4\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} r^{2} \exp\left[-\frac{Z}{a}r\right] \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \exp\left[-\frac{Z}{a}r\right] \right)  \ {\rm d}r \  \boldsymbol{\mathrm{e}}_{r} 
  = \frac{8Z}{a}i\hbar \boldsymbol{\mathrm{e}}_{r} 
\end{align}
I know it must be a wrong answer.

Yes, it is wrong. The expectation value of $\vec p$ is zero in any stationary state (at least for a Hamiltonian of the form $H=\frac{{\vec p}^2}{2m}+V(\vec x)$). (Or any real-valued state whatsoever, with appropriate boundary conditions.)

So, can we use the method in quantum to get the velocity $  v_n=\frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\boldsymbol{\hbar}}\frac1n $?

If I were you, I would use the Virial theorem:
$$
\langle 2T\rangle = m\langle \vec v^2\rangle = -\langle V\rangle = \frac{Z^2}{n^2}\;,
$$
where I am using atomic units ($\hbar=m=e^2=a_0=1$).
The second equals sign follows from the Virial theorem, and the third equals sign follows from the definition of the potential
$$
V = -\frac{Ze^2}{r}\;,
$$
in Gaussian cgs units,
and from the well-known expression
$$
\frac{Z}{a_0 n^2} = \langle \frac{1}{r}\rangle
$$
for a hydrogenic state.

What about good ol' probability current (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current)?

@JEB What about it?

@JEB I'm the one upvoting your comment; but if you consider it, you realise that each of the two terms making it up would integrate to zero individually, and thus it cannot be of help.
